# Flutter set datetime.now in GMT

Tags: flutter, dart, timezone

can i set `datetime.now()` in GMT timezone or can i set `datetime.now()` -7 hours ???

this is the variable

```
  String formattedDate = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss').format(DateTime.now());
```

im clueless

Comment: you mean in UTC may be? then DateTime.now().toUtc()

Comment: GMT is a time zone and UTC is a time standard. So you probably mean UTC `DateTime.now().toUtc() `

Comment: thank you so much, it works!!

Answer (score 1):

You can add or substract from a date time by using **Duration**.

```
 Date dateA =  someDate.subtract(Duration( hours: 6 ));
```

Comment: Probably want "subtract" not "substract".

Comment: Yes fixed now :)